# IntelliJ / WebStorm auto format quotes stopped working

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using TSLint and its set to allow single quotes (`'`) instead of double (`"`).

I used to be able to use the `Reformat Code` shortcut <kbd>CTRL + ALT + L</kbd> and this would automatically swap all occurrences of `"` to `'` in the file.

This has stopped working and I cant see a way to turn it back on in the settings... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Preferences : Editor : Code Style : Typescript`, to the `Punctuation` tab, then make sure you have `Use single quotes always`

Then reformat the file again (CTRL-ALT-L).

It may have stopped working because you switched code style schemes to one without the above setting.

You can do the same for Javascript to be consistent.